# 502 gateway errors with nginx php-fpm and wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, nginx, woocommerce

i have problems with one of 2 websites running on a centos server through NGINX + PHP-FPM.

For one of the websites running WordPress WooCommerce and a couple of plugins it feels like randomly getting 502 timeouts.

Especially on accessing category/archive or single product pages.

CPU and memory load is ok, also no errors or warnings here

What i can see from the logs is the following

/var/log/php-fpm/error.log

```
[27-Nov-2017 11:58:16] NOTICE: finished trace of 719
[27-Nov-2017 11:58:36] WARNING: [pool www] child 703, script '/srv/www/domain.com/public_htm/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") executing too slow (15.478662 sec$
[27-Nov-2017 11:58:36] NOTICE: child 703 stopped for tracing
[27-Nov-2017 11:58:36] NOTICE: about to trace 703
[27-Nov-2017 11:58:36] NOTICE: finished trace of 703
```

/var/log/nginx/domain-error.log

```
 [error] 30981#0: *18683 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 162.158.89.37, server: www.kixl.de, request: "GET /sneaker/asics HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9001",
```

---

thats pretty much it. Sometimes pages are reachable again, otherwise i have to restart php-fpm.

I would really like to find out the real reason behind these timeouts but don´t know where to look.

I already tried changing debug levels for NGINX and PHP-FPM to debug and more without getting more details what exactly causing the trouble.

I depend on the plugins and theme activated for this wordpress install so deactivating or using default theme is no option here.

Maybe someone can tell me how to find out what File, Plugin or maybe some database query causing PHP-FPM to hang, leading in the web server to timeout.

Comment: We might need some more details to help you with this issue. Is your PHP-FPM running on tcp or sockets?

Comment: TCP/IP (127.0.0.1:9001)

Comment: /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
https://codeshare.io/5Mbdqy

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
https://codeshare.io/aJQ9Zn

Comment: Server specs are: Intel® Core i7-6700 Quadcore, 32 GB DDR4 RAM, SSD

Comment: Try running PHP-FPM as sockets. 502 timeouts might be because of tcp. Or increase the timeout limit in /etc/php.ini

Comment: I did a complete reinstall of for the server. Optimized NGINX and PHP-FPM, also now running on sockets. All websites running fine / responding fast. Only problems with one WordPress site where i use WooCommerce and a couple of plugins. I am not sure if its a plugin related issue or theme conflict maybe. Is this even possible that code errors can cause the web server to timeout here? How to debug what script or maybe query if possible causes trouble if there are no logs instead of "timeout" giving a real reason for what causes it. I even tested all debug levels, but nothing...

Comment: Increasing time out by the way is not a solution. Its already high enough (120sec) Actually no action should take longer to complete. Would you wait 2 mins for a website to respond? I guess not...

Comment: That needs to be identified. If you can share nginx and php-fpm's log file we can help you. Before that, check if your WirdPress all other themes and plugins are up to date. Also if you can share the URL I might help you.